# How to make creating an object before performing another action required, in Java Spring REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

In my API, I have a class User and a class UserDetails (which is created with `@OneToOne` connection).

User is created when registration is executed (by sending UserRegistrationDTO using `@PostMapping("/auth/register))` but UserDetails needs sending another object with another URL `(@PostMapping ("user/createDetails"))`.

How to prevent taking further actions before UserDetails object is created?
Do I need - before using other functions - to check if object is created EVERY time?

Comment: Yes, if you don’t want User to be created without details. You can accomplish this by validating the User. The validation validates both User and UserDetails.